# Application Error on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm follow an online railstutorial.
I'm a newbie, and now I finished just my second app.
It works ok on a local machine, but I have a problem with heroku.
I pushing my app successfully, and then I done *heroku rake db:migrate*
But I see this error on [my page](http://strong-night-4868.heroku.com/)

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. Please try again in a few moments. If you are the application
>   owner, check your logs for details

And I see this warning in command line:

> rake aborted! Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install
>   activerecord-postgresql-adap ter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add
>   it to Gemfile.)

I google this error and found that I need add this strings to my gemfile:

> gem 'sqlite3', :group => :development
>   gem 'pg', :group => :production

Done it, and retried, but nothing changed, and I still have this in my command line

> Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install
>   activerecord-postgresql-adap ter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add
>   it to Gemfile.)

I can't understand it, cause I defenitely had *pg gem*, and I can see his installation on my local machine

```
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.2.1)
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Using jquery-rails (2.0.2)
Using pg (0.13.2)
Using rails (3.2.1)
Using sass (3.1.16)
Using sass-rails (3.2.5)
Using sqlite3 (1.3.6)
Using uglifier (1.2.4)
```

but I can't see the same, when bundle installing on heroku server

```
 Installing thor (0.14.6)
  Installing railties (3.2.1)
  Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  Installing jquery-rails (2.0.2)
  Using bundler (1.0.7)
  Installing rails (3.2.1)
  Installing sass (3.1.16)
  Installing sass-rails (3.2.5)
  Installing uglifier (1.2.4)
```

How can I solve it? Really have no idea. Please help me.

btw, sorry for my english, I'm from russia)

**update:**
yeah, i see that it runs bundle install --without development, but my gemfile now looks like:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
   gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
end
```

as you can see, 'pg' is definitely out of development group, but heroku didn't install it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you added the pg gem to the development group in your Gemfile - when Heroku deploys, it runs `bundle install --without development`, meaning that it'll not install gems in that group. Move the gem outside of the development group.

Answer (score 0):

If you've updated your Gemfile make sure you commit it and the Gemfile.lock to git and then repush your application to Heroku.

Comment: sure I commit it, and repush only after that